# WPF new Block on WordWrap

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, word-wrap

Is there a way to add a new Block on End of a RichTextBox in WPF?
With the RichTextBox.Document.MaxPageWidth no new block are created...

[image: RichTextBoxSample]

Convert the RichTextBox Content to Text:

```
if (rtb.Document != null)
            {
                TextRange textRange = new TextRange(                    
                    rtb.Document.ContentStart,                    
                    rtb.Document.ContentEnd
                );

                var currentLine = textRange.Text;
                //Result:
                //" thisText ist new textwith textwrap and here no new line after MaxPageWidth only is here\r\nafter press SHIFT+ENTER a new Line :(\r\n"
                return textRange.Text;
            }
```

is there a way to add \r\n after wordWrap e.g. after the "and" ?

Comment: You don't need to add a new block to the `RichTextBox` to brake a line after the and word when converting to a text. Enough to insert the **_New Line_** when converting to the `currentLine` string. Did you try this?

Comment: Here is the only way to count my chars and insert the NewLine,
but this only works on the same visualStyle - FontSize etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a Solution that works for me,
only on Paste with Style won't work.

On paste you i use a WordWrap Extension for String Text
with a hyphen after maxChars

```
private int maxCharsInLine = 30;     
       
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{           
   if (e.Key != Key.Back)
   {
      CheckMaxChars(e);
    }
 }
```

Check the richTextBox1 chars in actual line on
CaretPosition

```
private void CheckMaxChars(KeyEventArgs sender)
{
    var content = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(0));
    lblCaretPosParagraph.Content = content.Text.Length.ToString();

    var content2 = new TextRange(richTextBox1.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(0), richTextBox1.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(0));
    lblCaretPosParagraph_Copy1.Content = content2.Text.Length.ToString();

    var lengthInLine = content2.Text.Length;

    if (lengthInLine > maxCharsInLine)
    {
        if (sender.Key != Key.Space || !content2.Text.EndsWith(" "))
        {
            richTextBox1.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("-");
            richTextBox1.CaretPosition = richTextBox1.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(1);
        }
        RaiseNewLineKeyEvent();
    }
}
```

and the new Line is raised by Keyboard Enter

```
private int RaiseNewLineKeyEvent()
{
    keybd_event((byte)VK_RETURN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
    return 0;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D; // enter
```

and you can stop the new paragraph by set the Enter Key Down
like this:

```
private void richTextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                var newPointer = richTextBox1.Selection.Start.InsertLineBreak();
                richTextBox1.Selection.Select(newPointer, newPointer);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

i hope this helps anyone and i'm happy about every Improvment!